# When a stick that has been twisted into a knot burns, what happens to the potential energy?

Tags: potential-energy

> I tied a springy stick into a knot, giving it potential energy, because it could spring out of the knot shape. But then I threw it into a fire and it burned to ash without untying. What happened to the potential energy?

[Asking on behalf of /u/HomeWasGood on Reddit.](https://old.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/g9dmbk/i_tied_a_springy_stick_into_a_knot_giving_it/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to the potential energy of a compressed spring when it dissolves in acid?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72723/)

Comment: I disagree that the answer for this is the same as for a spring. I expect the energy ultimately winds up as heat, but the mechanism is different. Wet wood is springy. Dry wood is not. Wood dries as it burns. Wet wood left in a knot relaxes. If you untie it later, it will curl back up. Heated wood undergoes a phase transition from a solid stiff phase to a solid rubbery phase. This is much like the phase transition that makes it possible to iron clothes.